# How to extract only forced subtitles with a batch muxing using mkvmerge?

Tags: batch-file, video, mkv

There is an option to extract only forced subtitles using a windows script and mkvmerge.exe?

Now i use this script

```
for %%A IN (*.mkv) do (
"C:/Program Files/mkvtoolnix\mkvmerge.exe" -o "remux-%%~nA.mkv" -a ita "%%~A"
)
```

that extract only audio track with Italian language, but I can't find the way to extract only forced subtitles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try this, not tested with italien audio, but should work.

```
@echo off&setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
set "path=%path%;C:\Program Files\mkvtoolnix"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-s /b *.mkv') do (
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%b in ('mkvmerge --identify-verbose "%%a" ^| findstr /c:language:ita ^| findstr /c:forced_track:1') do (
        echo Processing "%%~a" with forced track ID %%~b
        mkvmerge -o "remux-%%~na.mkv" -s %%~b -a ita "%%~a"
    )
)
```

Comment: Great work, thanks for this. Can you do an edit in order to make the script works even if no forced subtitles are present? (and in this case no subtitles are muxed)

Comment: Yes, I can :-) but unfortunately not before Tuesday